# Python: appending to an array

Tags: python, parsing

I'm writing a solution in MATLAB but am using Python to parse a text file - Python is definitely not my strong point. Basically, I've managed to parse my text file for relevant lines and would like these exported as a tab delimited text file in the following format:

```
num1    num2    num3    num4    num5
num1    num2    num3    num4    num5
num1    num2    num3    num4    num5
num1    num2    num3    num4    num5
```

However, at present, my output file looks like this:

```
[num3, num1, num2, num4, num5], [num3, num1, num2, num4, num5], [num3, num1, num2, num4, num5], [num3, num1, num2, num4, num5]
```

My code looks like this:

```
for <blah blah>
    num3,num1,num2,num4,num5 = data
    outputData.append(data)
outfile.write("%s"%(outputData))
```

How do I rearrange the variables and have them output into a nice structured array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for <blah blah>
    num3,num1,num2,num4,num5 = data
    outputData.append('\t'.join(map(str, [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5])))

outfile.write('\n'.join(outputData))
```

The code `'\t'.join(map(str, [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5]))` will result in a tab-delimited string with the data in the correct order, so `outputData` will be a list of those strings.  Then `'\n'.join(outputData)` will combine all of the lines from `outputData` with a newline separating each line, which is what you want to write to the file.

Alternatively you could get rid of `outputData` entirely and do something like this:

```
for <blah blah>
    num3,num1,num2,num4,num5 = data
    outfile.write('\t'.join(map(str, [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5])) + '\n')
```

Comment: my 'num1', 'num2' etc are floats and doubles. How do I go about getting them converted into strings? (I assume this is what I have to do as I receive the error "expected string, float found")

Comment: @CaptainProg - `map(str, [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5])` will turn the list of floats into a list of strings, I edited my answer to add that.

Comment: Got it, yes, thanks very much for this. Python seems like a handy language to know